Pytorch incorrect results with non_blocking assignment from Cuda to CPU
I'm trying to assign a tensor on CPU with values I just obtained from GPU, however getting incorrect results, both tensors should be the same obviously:
(To avoid any unnecessary chatter, I'd like to mention beforehand that I'm also aware of exactly two other different methods of copying such as 1) using copy_ method and 2) by overwriting a variable altogether. However I find the first slower and second producing memory overhead, based on some of my tests. The assignment with semicolon seems to achieve best performance so far, albeit the obtained results are incorrect when non_blocking option is used.)
import torch
gpu = torch.device('cuda')
cpu = torch.device('cpu')

a = torch.rand((13223,134,4), dtype=torch.float32, device=cpu)
b = torch.rand((13223,134,4), dtype=torch.bfloat16, device=gpu)

for i in range(3):
    
    b.mul_(0.5)
    
    a[:] = b.to(device=cpu, memory_format=torch.preserve_format, dtype=torch.bfloat16, non_blocking=True)
    
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    
    print(b[0,0], a[0,0])


tensor([0.0942, 0.1621, 0.2041, 0.1543], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.bfloat16) tensor([0., 0., 0., 0.])
tensor([0.0471, 0.0811, 0.1021, 0.0771], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.bfloat16) tensor([0.0942, 0.1621, 0.2041, 0.1543])
tensor([0.0236, 0.0405, 0.0510, 0.0386], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.bfloat16) tensor([0.0471, 0.0811, 0.1021, 0.0771])
>>>

In my application the results are even weirder, as some of the values become negative! (...despite that none of them are negative in the original tensor). Appreciate any input in advance, the goal is to transfer data to CPU quickly and efficiently, and if you know any other methods that I haven't mentioned that will help me achieve that, do leave a comment. :)

Non-blocking assignments literally do not block the execution of the next statements.
You assume
a[:] = b.to(device=cpu, memory_format=torch.preserve_format, dtype=torch.bfloat16, non_blocking=True)

executed as
b_gpu -> b_cpu
b_cpu -> a
But with non_blocking, order of theese actions is not specified, allowing parallel execution. Yes, it gives speed! But b_cpu -> a works faster, and as it not wait for b_gpu -> b_cpu, order of execution effectively is
b_cpu -> a
b_gpu -> b_cpu

well, but what's your solution? it's kinda obvious already that it's not working

I solved it for now by creating a buffer:
import torch
gpu = torch.device('cuda')
cpu = torch.device('cpu')

a = torch.rand((13223,134,4), dtype=torch.float32, device=cpu)
b = torch.rand((13223,134,4), dtype=torch.bfloat16, device=gpu)

for i in range(3):
    
    b.mul_(0.5)
    
    buffer = b.to(device=cpu, memory_format=torch.preserve_format, dtype=torch.bfloat16, non_blocking=True)
    
    torch.cuda.synchronize()
    
    a[:] = buffer        
    
    print(b[0,0], a[0,0])

